# 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat: 4pm UTC on the 8th

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Tuesday the 8th at 4pm UTC, 11am EST.**

[(view in other timezones)](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=2&day=8&year=2011&hour=16&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)

**[click here to join](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/268/ask-ubuntu-town-hall-chat)**

Here are the details so far:

- I have coordinated with the candidates and done the best I could with a best fit match that everyone can make.
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=askubuntu.com).  You can [register for the event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/268/ask-ubuntu-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule).
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidate regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, the transcript of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: P.S. It didn't go to my spam folder.

Comment: I apologise in advance for my absence, I am more than happy to answer any questions though.

Comment: @fluteflute if you want to answer the Town Hall questions in the chat room after the fact, just notify me somehow and I will include them in my "digest" version.

Comment: @Josh Thank you, that's very kind. Would you mind if I just edited your posts to add them myself?

Answer (score 1):

As with the other town hall chats, I will be creating a "digest" version. This will be posted as one large Meta question. The digest will contain all the questions and their answers, with none of the other conversation from the room.

For more information, please see [the meta post about Town Hall Digests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests)

[Here is the Town Hall Digest Version](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/948/2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest)

Answer (score 0):

7-9th works for me as a range. I'm really not fussy which day.

Timing this is more awkward though. I'm UK based and I'm *less* available in the early evening.. So 5-8pm UTC is not really an option for me. Earlier might be an issue for the America-based people but much later might be a problem for me again.

4pm UTC would be a good time for me.

Comment: Replying to my email rather than adding an answer here could have worked...

Comment: Your email first pointed to this thread and then told me to reply. I'm sorry that I took that to mean come here and then reply. [Four candles?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qu9MptWyCB8)